# Php Codeigniter validations not working for me

Tags: php, codeigniter

hi i am currently learning code igniter i am pretty much new to this i have an issue with code igniter validations. I cant figure out what i am doing wrong please guide me.
currently what is happening is that whenever i submit with empty fields i am redirected to same page but when i populate the fields i am redirected to same page but the page is blank.
this is my user class

```
class User extends CI_Controller {

    function User() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->view_data['base_url'] = base_url();
    }

    function index() {

        $this->register();
    }

    function register() {

        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
            $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
        } else {
            $username=$this->input->post('username');
        }
    }

}
```

and this is my view_register.php (view)

```
<body>
    <h1>User Registration</h1>
    please fill in following details
    <?php
    echo form_open(base_url().'user/register');
    ?>
    <?php
    $username = array(
        'name' => 'username',
        'id' => 'username',
        'value' => ''
    );
    $password = array(
        'name' => 'password',
        'id' => 'password',
        'value' => ''
    );
    $con_password = array(
        'name' => 'con_password',
        'id' => 'con_password',
        'value' => ''
    );
    $email = array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'id' => 'email',
        'value' => ''
    );
    ?>

    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Username</label>
            <div>
                <?php echo form_input($username); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Email</label>
            <div>
                <?php echo form_input($email); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Password</label>
            <div>
                <?php echo form_password($password); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label>Confirm</label>
            <div>
                <?php echo form_password($con_password); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <?php echo form_submit(array('name' => 'register'), 'Register'); ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beacuse you're not loading a view in case validation is right, so CI calls again that controller, but displays nothing:

```
function register() {

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
    {
        $this->load->view('view_register', $this->view_data);
    } else
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $this->load->view('success');  // <------ put your view for success here
    }
}
```

Also, you should be opening the form with this, instead of your code:

```
 echo form_open('user/register');
```

it works out by itself the correct url (anologuely to site_url());

Try putting, also, `echo form_error('username')` under the username input to display the validation errors.

Comment: actually what i wanna say was that the$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha_numeric|min_length[6]');
are not working and thx for editing/correcting the else part

Comment: That looks ok to me...What's the exact problem? Did you corrected how you call the form_open() function?

Comment: yes i applied changes you suggested but still the validation(validation errors) are not working.

Comment: @noobie-php try reducing the rules to just "required" first, then go on until you see which one gives you problem. Do you echo validation errors out?

Comment: echo form_error('username');
this actually produced what was required.so i guess i have to do this with all the validations or is there any other way? From all i mean i have to do some thing like this
echo form_error('email'); echo form_error('password'); etc
echo form_error('email');

Comment: With all the field you want apply rules to. Otherwise you won't know what's failing. You can look on the manual for other ways to show errors, if you don't like this :)

Comment: echo validation_errors(); also helps and the way you suggested also helps thx for answering man.

Comment: Good!If you have other problems just ask. Cheers!